# Socket io doesn't emit second parameter

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am trying to send some text & numbers to client side. First parameter works fine and send data to server but second parameter says `undefined`
I am using following code

> Server Side

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {     
    randomHashtag.number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) +1);
    //var randomHashtag = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) +1);
    io.emit('stream',{text:tweet.text, number:randomHashtag.number});

});
```

> Client side

```
socket.on('stream', function(tweet,randomHashtag){//Stream tweets
    console.log(tweet.text);
    console.log(randomHashtag); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Socket.io is designed to send only one parameter. Or none. But that parameter can be anything. So if you need to send more than one value send an object:

```
// Server (you got this part right):
io.emit('stream',{text:tweet.text,number:randomHashtag.number});

// Client:
socket.on('stream', function(data){
    var tweet = data.text;
    var randomHashtag = data.number;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with socket.io but I guess that the event receives only the object that you emitted previously:

```
socket.on('stream', function(data){//Stream tweets
    console.log(data.text);
    console.log(data.number); 
});
```